# Rotate Table headers according to screen size

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, rotation

I am trying to rotate the table headers according to the screen size. Like if there are 20 headers and they are not fitting the screen then rotate them to fit the screen.

css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers
I am trying to make this type of table. But it is not responsive. If there are few titles then they shouldn't be rotated and evenly distributed on the page. If there are many then they should be rotated at 315 and evenly distributed on the page. Similarly rotated at -90 to show enough title evenly distributed on the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you require. In addition to providing the code you have tried so far please describe exactly what is to happen if the headers collectively are too long. For example, are they all to be rotated and is that by 90degrees always?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/

I am trying to make this type of table. But it is not responsive. If there are few titles then they shouldn't be rotated and evenly distributed on the page. If there are many then they should be rotated at 315 and evenly distributed on the page. Similarly rotated at -90 to show enough title evenly distributed on the page.